# Can not pass useState variable inside array find method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, filter

I was need to find an object from an array by its id value. I am using array find function.

```
const onUpdateExercise = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const form = e.target
      var id = 3
      const ex = exercises.find(item => item.id === id)
      console.log(ex);
}
```

In this code it is working fine but...

```
const onUpdateExercise = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const form = e.target
      var id = 3
      const ex = exercises.find(item => item.id === currentId) // currentId is useState variable, value is same, 3
      console.log(ex);
}
```

... but here this code is not working although currentId value is same as id.

Why currentId is not passing but id passing to find function?
And what is the best way to find an array element (object) with dynamic id

**Full code**

```
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0)
const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'Bench press', defaultSets: 4, defaultReps: 8 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Overhead press', defaultSets: 4, defaultReps: 8 },
        { id: 3, name: 'Triceps push down', defaultSets: 4, defaultReps: 12 },
        { id: 4, name: 'Skullcrusher', defaultSets: 4, defaultReps: 12 }
    ])

const onUpdateExercise = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const form = e.target
        var id = 3
        // currentId is 3 after clicking a button
        const ex = exercises.find(item => item.id === currentId)
        console.log(ex);
    }
```

Comment: It may be related to the type of `currentId`. During the `setCurrentId`, it can be changed to `string` so the `item.id === currentId` won't be evaluated to `true`. Provide more context for how you do the set action.

Comment: How is `onUpdateExercise` being called? Maybe you're invoking an old version of it that has a closure of the old state.

Comment: You were right @SMAKSS . There was definitely a type casting issue with ===, I changed it to == and it returning true now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useEffect hook to ensure that you're working with the latest value of currentId after it has been updated.

```
  const onUpdateExercise = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = e.target;
    var id = 3;
    setCurrentId(id); // Update currentId
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const ex = exercises.find((item) => item.id === currentId);
    console.log(ex);
  }, [currentId, exercises]);
```

Comment: The idea is good but I don't need that much of code. The find method can't search the element because item.id === currentId will never satisfy because data type not matching here. Instead I was need to use == here. It's working fine. Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: This isn't a Javascript closure issue, it's a variable type issue.